# Qtip timeout needs to disabled

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to increase or hide `qtip` timeout 
whenever hover other column tool-tip should go otherwise it should stay.

I used below code but it is not working

```
'data-qdismissDelay=0' +
'data-qautoHide=false';

metadata.tdAttr =
    'data-qtitle="' +
    ''
Title +
    '<br>' +
    'data-qtip="'
show sample from database ' + 
'data-qwidth=1040' +
'data-qdismissDelay=0' +
```

I tried this code but then my tooltip wont go away

```
return '<span data-qtitle="QTip Example" data-qwidth="200" '+
                    'data-qtip="This is a quick tip from a custom renderer!"  data-hide=' + false + '>'+
                    value+'</span>';
```

Comment: I doubt that you can do that with QTip. You may have to use a full-blown ToolTip for that, where you can modify everything.

Comment: I tried this code but then tool tip wont go away its stay there only                                                                                  return '<span data-qtitle="QTip Example" data-qwidth="200" '+
                        'data-qtip="This is a quick tip from a custom renderer!"  data-hide=' + false + '>'+
                        value+'</span>';